# American standard toilet trip lever rod stuck on adjustment knob

Tags: toilet

[[image][adjustment knob circled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ox5HO.jpg)putting in a new American Standard toilet and the trip lever rod blocks the float from coming up — the adjustment knob is getting caught on the rod. Any suggestions?
I tried bending the rod out of the way but it doesn’t stay bent, also it is pretty flimsy plastic and I don’t want to break it.

Comment: Pic may help. Sometimes you can bend the rod, or even snip off a bit. As long as it lifts correctly so water exits tank, and drops fine so tank can fill, it is all good.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Yes, the problem is that when the float rises, the adjustment knob hits the trip lever rod, so the float can’t rise high enough to stop filling the tank

Comment: Looks as though you could rotate the float counter-clockwise to solve. It also looks like you can just cut the black plastic off the end where it touches, but if it were me I would get a brass lever which are narrow and would not touch. Wanna go totally experimented, try gently heating the plastic and putting a bend in it

Comment: Yes, my wife figured out that you can unlock the float and rotate it! It is working now. Thanks all.

Comment: Thanks for the tip.  You should post it as an answer and get valuable points that can redeemed for....well nothing...but they're still cool!

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to unlock the float tower and then turn it to reposition the knob so it no longer hits the top rod. Turn off the water supply first.

Comment: How did you unlock the float?

Comment: Just turned it I think?